# Twitter summary card with large image not working

Tags: twitter, meta-tags, twitter-card

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@nytimes">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@SarahMaslinNir">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Parade of Fans for Houston’s Funeral">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="NEWARK - Thenter code heree guest list and parade of limousines with celebrities emerging from them seemed more suited ">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2012/02/19/us/19whitney-span/19whitney-span-articleLarge.jpg">
```

I have used all the above meta tags, but still the image appears only as a summary card rather than displaying a summary card with large image.

Comment: Some times it's just a chache issue, try clearing chaches of your website

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing your code on a test page, html only. Everything worked fine for me. Here is also the Tweet generated with only the meta tags inside.

Looks to me more, there are other problems inside the html that might cause wrong interpretation of your meta tags.

[image]